# NextJs13 : Method Not Allowed (405 code) while redirecting in Route Handler

Tags: typescript, redirect, next.js, next.js13

NextJs version : 13.4.3

I created a route handler to capture a POST request. Route handler doc : [https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers]

In this handler, I only redirect to an url of my website.

**Code :**

```
import { type NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  // Delete "api" in the url
  const newUrl = request.url.replace('/api', '');
  redirect(newUrl);
}
```

**Error :**
When a POST request is captured, I'm redirecting but I get a Next 405 error code

[image: 405 error code]

If I replace the url of my website by another random url like (facebook.com, google.com, whatever.com), it works perfectly without getting an error.

Could it be because my site does not support 302 redirections?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: do you have a route registered at localhost:3000/?

Comment: @SiddharthSathe Yes. Moreover, if I refresh the page on which I am redirected (and where I see the code 405), it works.

Comment: a relative or absolute url should work, give it a try

Comment: I've been testing for hours with absolute or relative urls to my site and it doesn't work. It only works with absolute urls to other sites. Very weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be because Next uses code **307** and **308** for redirects. However, only a redirect with code **302** can transform a POST request into a GET request.
I tried :

```
Response.redirect('url', 302)
```

but got the same error.

I had to use a Clouflare worker to get it to work. The POST request is sent to the worker url, and the worker redirects to an url in my application (https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/)

Answer (score 2):

This route did work (next v13.4.12):

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST({ nextUrl: { origin } }: NextRequest) {
/**
 * 1)
 * NextResponse.redirect requires an absolute url. 
 * "origin" is used here to get protocol, host and port. For instance
 * origin of http://localhost:3000/api/foo is "http://localhost:3000"
 *
 * 2)
 * status should be 303, browser will redirect with method GET, see
 * MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/303
 */
  return NextResponse.redirect(`${origin}/bar`, { status: 303 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
redirect(new URL('/api', request.url)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. `redirect` accepts only a string. I tried to add "`toString()` after `new Url(...)`, but it doesn't work. Same issue.

In my middleware, I use `return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/relativePath', request.url))` and it works. So I also tried to use it in my api, but it doesn't work there.